# Is it normal for 12.04 to occupy almost 4GB?

Tags: 12.04, installation, asus

I'm using a ASUS EeePC 901 and have some basic questions/issues. I installed 12.04 on the 4GB drive, selecting the option to erase it before doing so. Immediately after the installation I saw that Update Manager had over 100 updates pending. I attempted to install these, but was told that I had less than 100 MB remaining. Does the OS occupy all the other space?

It seems that the best solution is to install 12.04 on the 16GB drive. Is this true?

If I do this, what is the best way to erase the 4GB drive afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Here the official help pages.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/

Requirement when installing Ubuntu

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/amd64/minimum-hardware-reqts.html

Here the recommend requirement for Ubuntu 12.04 by the community

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

On how to install visit this help pages

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm familiar with this info and my device meets the system requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The best choice (I've tried on my EEE 900 4 GB + 16 GB) is to use manual partition and create on the 16 GB SSD another partition of about 2.5 or 3 GB.

When you install and select the partitions and mounting points you have to select to mount as following:

1. Mount `/` in the 4 GB partition, so you will get the most of the highest speed of that SSD card when booting up and for main tasks.
2. Mount `/var` in the 2.5 GB partition on the 16 GB SSD.
3. Mount `/home` in the 13.5 GB partition left in the 16 GB SSD.

This way you will:

- use about 3 GB on the 4 GB fast SSD improving your speed.
- let about 1 GB free in the main partition to update, upgrade and to let the system run smoothly.
- will let `/var` increase up to 2.5 GB without the chance to fill up the `/` partition and mess it up.

I am using this *config* and works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. What happens is that normally the OS takes about 3GB uncompressed, and also uses about 1GB for Swap (the swap partition).

The best option is to install on the 16GB drive, and you can wipe the 4GB drive from the installer (using advanced partitioning options) or from Gparted (on a live USB/CD or after installing on the 16.

Comment: Thanks for this quick and helpful info. Since I got it, I've been searching for info on erasing a drive using advanced partitioning options or gparted. So far what I've found has not made much sense. Can you point me toward step-by-step instructions on either of these methods?

Comment: @Grant: that would be a little difficult to do (as in the installer part), but I'll try.

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate that. Since my last comment, I've done the following:

Comment: 1. Attempted to install to the 16gb drive: "Installation has crashed." 2. Formatted the 16gb drive with Disk Utility. Tried to do the same for the 4gb drive, but "drive is busy." 3. Attempted twice more to install to the 16gb drive. The first time I took the option to "reinstall," and the next time this was not available, so I chose "erase and install." There was no message about a crash after either attempt, but neither was successful. There was the same message each time, re: not being able to install all requested components.

Comment: Currently I cannot boot to either drive; attempts to do this for either drive result in a black screen with white blinking cursor in the top left, and the system unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

For the past releases of Ubuntu, the consensus was NOT creating the Swap partition, as it was not useful with SSD disks.

I have also tried installing 12.04 on my 901, but the end result was the same as with Grant: a blank screen.